# CGContextClipToMask is not clipping Image in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uigraphicscontext

I am trying to save a `UIImage` to the Photos gallery and am using the following method to do so:

```
func savePhoto() {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: device.x, height: device.y), false, 2.0)
    CGContextClipToRect(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), self.drawingCanvas)
    self.mainImageView.image?.drawInRect(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: device.x, height: device.y), blendMode: CGBlendMode.Normal, alpha: 1.0)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, "image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:", nil)
}
```

The image saves successfully, but the problem is that the image is not cropped to the size of the `CGRect drawingCanvas` but the exported image is the size of the respective screen.

Since `drawingCanvas` is only the size of about 2/3 of the screen, a large blank white area is left in the final image.

Also, if I print `CGContextGetClipBoundingBox(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())` it prints the correct size, which is the same as `drawingCanvas`.

Anyone know why the final image is not being clipped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CoreGraphics is clipping exactly how it's supposed to. "Clip" means "for subsequent drawing calls, draw only inside the rect I provide, and don't draw outside of it". That's why there are white areas outside of the image that you see.

Clipping does *not* make your context smaller, and does *not* make the result image smaller. Clipping is not the same as cropping.

If you want the result image to be smaller, you should change the size that you pass to `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`. It does not have to be based on any particular device.

It's unclear from your question what size you really want. But, if you want it to be based on the size of the drawing canvas, use that instead:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.drawingCanvas, false, 2.0)
self.mainImageView.image?.drawInRect(CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size:self.drawingCanvas))
let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Comment: Kurt, thanks for the detailed info. I was definitely under the impression that clip meant crop. Wih this info I have solved my issue.